# Is there a way to go through rows in a pandas data frame more efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge pandas data frame where each row corresponds to a single sports match. It looks like the following:

**EDIT: I'll change the example code to better reflect the actual data:
This made me realize the presence of values other than 'lost' or 'won' makes this a lot more difficult.

```
d = {'date': ['21.01.96', '22.02.96', '23.02.96', '24.02.96', '25.02.96',
          '26.02.96', '27.02.96', '28.02.96', '29.02.96', '30.02.96'], 
     'challenger': [5, 5, 10, 5, 4, 5, 8, 8, 10, 8],
     'opponent': [2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 10, 5, 2, 4, 10],
     'outcome': ['win', 'lost', 'declined', 'win', 'declined', 'win', 'declined', 'declined', 'lost', 'lost']
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

For each matchup I want to calculate previous wins/losses in a new variable. In the example case, the 'prev_wins' variable would be [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. I did manage to create working code for this, which looks like this:

```
data['prev_wins_spec_challenger'] = 0
data['prev_losses_spec_challenger'] = 0               

data['challenger'] = data['challenger'].astype(str)
data['opponent'] = data['opponent'].astype(str)

data['matchups'] = data['challenger'] + '-' + data['opponent']

# create list of matchups with unique pairings
matchups_temp = list(data['matchups'].unique())
matchups = []
for match in matchups_temp:
    if match[::-1] in matchups:
        pass
    else:
        matchups.append(match)

prev_wins = {}
for i in matchups:
    prev_wins[i] = 0

prev_losses = {}
for i in matchups:
    prev_losses[i] = 0

# go through data set for each matchup and calculate variables
for i in range(0, len(matchups)):
    match = matchups[i].split('-')
    challenger = match[0]
    opponent = match[1]
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        if row['challenger'] == challenger and row['opponent'] == opponent:
            if row['outcome'] == 'won':
                data['prev_wins_spec_challenger'][index] = prev_wins[matchups[i]]
                prev_wins[matchups[i]] += 1
            elif row['outcome'] == 'lost':
                data['prev_losses_spec_challenger'][index] = prev_losses[matchups[i]]
                prev_losses[matchups[i]] += 1
        elif row['challenger'] == opponent and row['opponent'] == challenger:
            if row['outcome'] == 'won':
                data['prev_losses_spec_challenger'][index] = prev_losses[matchups[i]]
                prev_losses[matchups[i]] += 1
            elif row['outcome'] == 'lost':
                data['prev_wins_spec_challenger'][index] = prev_wins[matchups[i]]
                prev_wins[matchups[i]] += 1
```

The problem with this is that it takes incredibly long cause there are a total of ~65.000 different matchups and the data frame has ~170.000 rows. On my laptop this would take around 180 hours to run, which is not acceptable.

I am sure there is a better solution for this but even after searching the internet the whole day I was not able to find one. How can I make this code faster?

Comment: Can you please show the expected output? I don't follow `[0, 0, 1]` from your example. The first win is ignored and therefore is `0` because there are no prior wins?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am only interested in the prior wins and losses, from the perspective of the 'challenger'. So in the first row there is no prior win / loss, the second time the matchup turns up in row 3 shows one win cause of the first row.

Comment: I can't help you at the moment because I'm on mobile, but if nobody is answering (which I doubt will happen), you must look at how the method ".loc" works, and you'll significantly increase the speed. You should also look at an apply or applymap method :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

```
df['outcome'] = df.outcome.map({'win':1, 'loss':0})
```

Then

```
df.groupby('challenger').outcome.cumsum().sub(1).clip(lower=0)
```

Of course, you don't need to overwrite the values in `outcome` (you can create a new column and work with it). But usually in pandas operations are way faster when working with `int`s than when working with `string`s. So from a performance point-of-view, it is preferable to have `0` and `1` representing wins and losses than having the actual words `loss` and `win`.

In the last layer, just when you are presenting the information, that's when you map back to human-understandable words. But the processing don't usually need strings

Comment: Nevermind this actually doesn't work at all. For the first few rows of the data frame it gives me this: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], where the matchups are ['5-2', '5-4', '10-5', '5-4', '4-5', '5-10', '8-5', '8-2', '10-4', '8-10', '4-8', '5-8'] For the matchup 5-10 it should be 1 previous win (cause 10-5 was a loss for 10), not 2.

Comment: @Denzo mind editing and posting this example in the question? with the matchups and win-loss info?

Comment: I updated it to be exactly like the first 10 rows in the actual data now.

Comment: @Denzo thanks! but your output seems odd. Should the second value be 1?

Comment: Why would the second value be one? The second matchup is 5 vs 4, which hasn't occured yet, so there aren't any previous wins or losses.

Comment: @Denzo oh, I thought the opponent didn't matter. `5` had player before and `won`, against `10`, so I thought it would have a previous win.

Comment: Yeah sorry I am having a hard time explaining what it is that I am trying to accomplish lol.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do something like this, using `shift()` to look at the previous outcomes, and getting the cumulative sum of the boolean of where it is equal to `win`:

```
data['previous_wins'] = data.groupby('challenger').outcome.transform(lambda x: x.shift().eq('win').cumsum())

>>> data
   challenger      date  opponent outcome  previous_wins
0           5  21.01.96         6     win              0
1           4  22.02.96         3    loss              0
2           5  23.02.96         6     win              1
```

If you're looking to count how many wins a challenger had against a specific opponent, you can just groupby both the challenger and opponent:

```
data['previous_wins'] = data.groupby(['opponent','challenger']).outcome.transform(lambda x: x.shift().eq('win').cumsum())
```

Comment: You're correct, the opponent does not really matter in this case. Thanks for the answer, this will definitly be helpful, but it seems like it's not quite working yet. It works fine on the test example but if I run it on the actual data the first few rows look like the following:
5-2, 0
5-4, 1
10-5, 0
5-4, 1

Comment: Sorry yeah that was my bad. I forgot that there are more than just 'win' and 'loss' values in the outcome variable. Now it works perfectly. Thank you so much!